# Summation of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x (n+1/2+\sin(\frac{a}{b} \pi (n+1/2)))}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers. Is there a closed form for the following sum?

$$F(x,a,b)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-x (n+1/2+\sin(\frac{a}{b} \pi (n+1/2)))}$$

Comment: Is that $\sin\left(\frac ab\pi(n+1/2)\right)$?  Just for clarification

Comment: Yes; I'll add that in

Comment: by the way, all the sums you consider will be dominated by the first few terms, so looking for a consistent approximation scheme might be a good way to follow (instead of solving everything exactly)

Answer (score 1):

For each particular $b$, it will have a closed form: since the $\sin$ term depends only on $n \mod (2b)$, this reduces to the sum of $2b$ geometric series. I doubt that there is a closed form expression as a function of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

We can approximate in the following manner:

$$F(x)\approx\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-x(n+1/2)}=\frac{e^{-x/2}}{1-e^{-x}}$$